# Login with Facebook error:"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in[..]"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am seeing the following error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in [...]"

My code is like this:

```
session_start();
require_once("../../src/composer/vendor/facebook/autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '****','****' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/signup/withfacebook/' );

try {
   $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
   // When Facebook returns an error
}catch( Exception $ex ) {
   // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
   // graph api request for user data
   $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
   $response = $request->execute();

   // get response
   $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
   $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');           // To Get Facebook ID
   $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name');   // To Get Facebook full name
   $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');      // To Get Facebook email ID

   /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
   $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
   $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
   $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;

   /* ---- header location after session ----*/
   header("Location: index.php");
}else {
   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
   header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

I use the facebook graph api v5 downloaded with composer from: "https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk?fbclid=IwAR09B8JjgOMlCQTm5x4gdxbQmLjMHVVsUeepx9_2pAvO9LImDX8MYic8TMo"

It's the official facebook github page.

Comment: Try to require file manually and see if work.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2d8250638b33d73e7a87add65f47fabf91f8ad9b/CHANGELOG.md#L81: _“5.0 (2015-07-09): […] Codebase changes […] Killed FacebookSession in favor of the AccessToken entity”_ - the `FacebookSession` class does not exist any more in the SDK version you are using …

Comment: Thanks, i will change the skd version.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the location of autoload.php is correct?

Can you write;

```
echo "example";
die();
```

into autoload.php?

It writes an example in white on the screen and stops working

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mv5I.jpg)

The autoload.php location you specified is incorrect if it does not display an "example" on the screen.

change require_once position until you find the correct position, that is, until you see "example" on the screen

Comment: Hello,
The "sample" appeared on the first attempt, so the path of the file is correct.